# Query by joining a particular partition of a table with another table returns partial fields

Tags: java, jooq

On execution of the below statement, the result record only has fields for table B, but if I replace select() with select(A.fields()).select(B.fields()) , I get fields for both A and B, is this expected behavior? I would assume to get all fields just like when doing a regular join.

```
DSL.using(configuration())
                .select()
                .from(DSL.table("{0} partition (p2)", A))
                .join(B)
                .on(A.ID.eq(B.A_ID))
                .where(A.ID.eq(uuid))
                .fetchOne()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in jOOQ, caused by the fact that a plain SQL table is mixed with a non-plain SQL table. jOOQ should generate a `SELECT *` query (as the columns of the plain SQL table are unknown to jOOQ). The relevant issue is:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7231

#### Workarounds:

- Explicitly select all columns (as you've mentioned in the question), e.g. through:

  ```
  .select(A.fields()).select(B.fields())
  ```
- Make sure all tables in the `FROM` clause are plain SQL tables:

  ```
  .from("{0} partition (p2)", A").join("{0}", B).on(...)
  ```